# Typescript - How to assign Partial type to the property of same type of another object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing Unit Test cases for which I need very limited properties from the objects.

Now there is one case in which I assign a Partial object to another object's property of T type.
But TS errors out that I can't assign Partial to the T type, which I understand should be the case.

But then how am I supposed to assign the object.

Below is the sample example I'm trying to solve.

```
const a: Partial<A> = {
  a1: "my a1 prop"
};
const b: Partial<B> = {
  b1: "my b1 prop",
  b2: a,
}
// A: {a1: string, a2: string, a3: string}
// B: {b1: string, b2: A, b3: string}
```

So, here I want to assign the "a" object to the "b2" property *without creating the* **whole "a" object**.

Now, the Partial makes the b2 property optional but it doesn't make all the nested properties optional as well.

So, is there *any way* for me to achieve this assignment without creating the whole "a" object first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely you want a `DeepPartial` which is like `Partial` but recurses down through properties.  You can define it like this:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> }
```

And then use it instead of `Partial`:

```
const a: DeepPartial<A> = {
    a1: "my a1 prop"
};
const b: DeepPartial<B> = {
    b1: "my b1 prop",
    b2: a
} // okay
```

Does that meet your needs?  Hope it helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8UA3lANoDSUGAdlANYQgD2AZlPgLoD8ALljwkaTDgK1exAL4BYAFBLGwCKk7IAxtACCFKMgCMwgM7BUjAOYAaQwCYzF63eQBmJ5YZWoCxavVNHSgAIQMAIxMocy9bKHDHKF07cI9o529fJSUtdgZzQ2E4BBR0LDxdYjJyJSg6wyiAIgBbEAaoMFR2MEalWQBuHLyC8KLRUok8EKqDWvrI4Ra2yI6unps5uoThZA3FPyA)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.
Just one thing, I only needed to make "b" as "DeepPartial". I kept "a" still as "Partial".

Answer (score 2):

You can set type `b2` as `Partial`:

```
type A = { a1: string; a2: string; a3: string };
type B = { b1: string; b2: A; b3: string };

type B1 = { b1: string; b2: Partial<A>; b3: string };
```

Or use `DeepPartial`

```
type DeepPartial<T> = T extends Function ? T : T extends object ? { [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]> } : T;
type B2 = DeepPartial<B>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGBGAXFAzsATgJYB2A5gNxoBM2eRZlqAzLQSaVAL7kCwAUKEhQAQgmRQARllxsGkmrEoSWM+h279+g6MPRiUU1mqUKACqnzBCqADYAeGAD4lKuuy68+-AMYB7Ynho0uaW1vZO+vxQ0UHYAOQAtiBBUGD4vmBxADT8Gnx+AcCSwRZWtna6jpF8McXxScWp6Zk5NTESChiteVrg0AAiEBBgIWX2ACpViONQEAAewBDEACY4UABiAK7E3lb+UAD8UDPYM-OLK2u+EgBWELuH4gDaplAkUADWECC+AGbHAF0DthBsNRmE7OMXgCqpwoKdPNoRFQxKCRqUIcJnJp8v5AqgzBjyhFEEgojEMPVkhgmhlsrlPAVAh1sMIUaTydFDFBEskpLSWpz5NgCd1yEA)